# Determine the direction vector with accelerometer to concrete locations - Augmented Reality

Tags: android, c++, gps, augmented-reality, android-sensors

Let's say we have specific points and their coordinates(lon,lat,height over sea lvl). Also we can get our current mobile gps coordinates(lon,lat) and device orientattion based on accelerometer sensor output vector([x,y,z]) .

With this we want to show direction from current location to those input coordinates. How can we go with this?

Comment: Technically an accelerometer can't show you (x, y) device orientation to any degree of accuracy, for that you need a compass. Luckily, smart phones tend to have a compass inside so you can work out the orientation using the accelerometer and compass.

Comment: why not using the orientation sensor of the device? :o

Comment: have a look here, the last function computes the angle between your current gps location and a given gps location: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21928670/android-simple-augmented-reality-with-gps/21952364#comment33307659_21952364

Comment: I try to use now formula cos(angle(x,y)). Where x y are vectors(current, and expected).